# Cascading a date & absolute value that references another dated sheet

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTyyem2spUQAi44lPN3rk_AQiE1J-OS2nQtJbASYadyXZ8WmjHR-yNjY1fH2jRwttyUiOPtf6uL3xBs/pubhtml

I'd like to be able to click and drag to auto-populate the cells instead of having to F2 each cell and have to change each date.  The D4 cell looks like ='8/1'!$V$49, I'd love to be able to click and drag so it becomes ='8/2'!$V$49, ='8/3'!$V$49...and so on.  Please and thank you!!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Your spreadsheet has been "published" as html which means that the data and formula can't be identified, and volunteers can't make a copy of the spreadsheet for testing. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet to anyone with the url. You might care to share a as a "viewer" only so that you original sheet isn't accidentally changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell D4:

`=indirect(address(2,5,4,true,"8/"&row()-3))`

---

- `INDIRECT` returns the value of the cell specified by the address
- `ADDRESS` returns a cell reference

  - the 5th (and optional) parameter of `ADDRESS` is a sheet name
  - `"8/"&row()-3)` - recognises a sheet name that begins with the characters "8/" and is followed by a number. The number is created by the row of the current cell, 4, (cell is D4) less 3 = 1. So the sheet name = "8/1"
  - drag that down and the row number will increment by one, so the sheet name will progressively become "8/2", "8/3", etc.

**Documentation**

[Indirect](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
[Address](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308)
[Row](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)

Answer (score 0):

### Indirect & Concatenate

---

**Assumptions**:

1. 'sheetName' is in column 'A', and that does not change ($A).
2. Each row has a different 'sheetName'. I will use $A[i] where 'i' refers to the applicable row.
3. 'sheetNames' are in the format 'M/D'
4. Goal is a concatenation of the 'sheetName' ($A[i]) & 'cellRef' ($V$49)
5. Formula will updated as it is pasted or dragged across multiple rows.

**The Gotcha**
The fly in the ointment is the data in column 'A' which isn't text but is actually a big number (dateTime) displayed as a short text string (M/D).

```
  Where you see     8/1  |     8/2  |     8/3

  Formula sees   44,774  |  44,775  |  44,776
```

So, that number needs to be converted to actual text before concatenating.

```
  Basic conversion formula    =TEXT(value,"format")
  So in your case             =TEXT($A[i], "M/D")
  
  EXAMPLE
  -------
  =TEXT($A[i], "M/D")    //   $A[i]  =  8/1
  =TEXT(44774, "M/D")    //    8/1   =  44,474
  ="8/1"                 //   "8/1" !=  44,474
```

Now that we have the 'sheetName' we can concatenate it with the 'cellRef'

```
  Concatenation formula

  = quote (') & 'sheetName' &  quote (') exclMark (!) & 'cellRef'

  = "'" &TEXT($A[i],"M/D") &"'!" &$V$49
    OR
  = "'" &TEXT($A[i],"M/D") &"'!$V$49"   // since 'cellRef' never changes

  = "'"&TEXT(44774,"M/D")&"'!$V$49"    //  $A[i] = 8/1 (Aug 1, 2022)
  = "'"&"8/1"&"'!$V$49"  
  = "'8/1'!$V$49"
```

All that remains is to wrap it in an INDIRECT formula.

```
Indirect Formula   = INDIRECT(textString)     // A1 Notation (default/unspecified)
So in your case    = INDIRECT(ConcatFormula)
```

**Assumptions**

1. Cell '$V$49' on sheet '8/1' equals "This is 8/1"
2. And '$A[i]' equals the date '8/1'

```
                   = INDIRECT("'" &TEXT($A[i],"M/D") &"'!$V$49")
                   = INDIRECT("'8/1'!$V$49")
                   = "This is 8/1"
```

**NB**
If you do not a 'sheetName' in '$A[i]' without a sheet with that name.  Your formula will generate an error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]